# Elm: How to add an onload div

Tags: javascript, leaflet, onload, elm

Let's say i have

```
view: Model -> Html Msg
view model = 
     div [ id "map" , onClick portDisplayMap ] [ text "Render Leaflet Map" ]
```

What i want to do is , i wish to add an onload event into this because port done after the page is loaded completely. I have issue which is the `map` id take time to mount on the function in Js.So, the map is not display properly sometimes.

Tried :

```
div [ id "map" , onClick portDisplayMap , onload "functionPreLoad()" ] [ text "Render Leaflet Map" ]
```

This is not working as i know. Idea is trying to render the `map` 's id before the page is loaded completely. Wish to get help from anyone. Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your use case.
You can trigger a port in the `init` function of your program to render the leaflet map inside your div.
If you still have  the problem that the div does not always exist, you can wrap your js instantiation code inside a `requestAnimationFrame` callback. With this change adding the leaflet to the div will only execute after the next DOM paint has finished and the div definitely exists.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for answering. Thats correct method